# Need help configuring apache .conf file

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-deployment

I want to deploy my django app on a Apache 2.4 server. The same server will host static files. The thing is that this server hosts other php based web sites.
In order for all this to work I just need to install `mod_wsgi` and configure apache's `.conf` file related to this web site, is that right?

After reading few articles I came up with this config, assuming that the web site will be in the `var/www/` folder :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
#   Alias /events /var/www/events/html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

            Alias /media/ /var/www/example/media/
            Alias /static/ /var/www/example/static/

            <Directory /var/www/example/static>
            Order deny,allow
            Require all granted
            </Directory>

            <Directory /path/to/example/media>
            Order deny,allow
            Require all granted
            </Directory>

            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example/events_promgruz/wsgi.py
            WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/example:/opt/envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages
            WSGIProcessGroup example.com

            <Directory /path/to/example/example>
            <Files wsgi.py>
            Order allow,deny
            Require all granted
            </Files>
            </Directory>

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

What would you suggested to change or add to config?
Is there some other steps to ensure that django app will work and that it doesn't interfere other non wsgi apps?

Comment: Does it work currently?

Comment: Add `LogLevel degug` to see all entries, and try it.  If you have problems, identify the source, debug, and *if* you have issues, you can post here if your research does not show anything.  But I see nothing critically wrong in your config.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I can't tell, I need to be sure other apps won't chash after I install `wsgi`. PHP apps work fine now, can wsgi interrupt them in some way?

Comment: @Nic3500 that's what I wanted to hear, that it's not that bad. I will have an opportunity to test it tomorrow. I'll update the post comment after.

Comment: Don't forget to add `</VirtualHost>` at the end :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName expample-domen.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
Alias /static /var/www/example/static
Alias /media /var/www/example/media

<Directory /var/www/example/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/example/media>
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/example/example>
<Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess example python-home=/path/to/virtualEnv python-path=/var/www/example
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example/example/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```